# One Row Query Double counting Sum

Tags: mysql, sql

The query below works when a record only has data in one of the columns (e or f). However, if the record has data in both columns, it is causing b and c to double count, naturally. So, how can i combat this?

```
SELECT  a.User1
        , isnull(sum(b.Page_Count),0) AS Count1
        , isnull(sum(c.Page_Count),0) AS Count2
        , isnull(sum(d.Page_Count),0) AS Count3
        , e.Material_Location
        , f.Material_Location
From    TaskUser AS a
    LEFT JOIN PaperMaterial AS b
    ON b.Assigned_To = a.User1
    AND b.Date_Assigned between ('06/11/2014') AND ('06/12/2014')
    LEFT JOIN PaperMaterial AS c
    ON c.Assigned_To = a.User1
    AND c.Date_Assigned between ('06/12/2014') AND ('06/13/2014')
    LEFT JOIN PaperMaterial AS d
    ON d.Assigned_To = a.User1
    AND d.Date_Assigned between ('06/09/2014') AND ('06/14/2014')
    LEFT JOIN PaperMaterial AS e
    ON e.Assigned_To = a.User1
    AND e.Date_Assigned between ('06/11/2014') AND ('06/12/2014')
    LEFT JOIN PaperMaterial AS f
    ON f.Assigned_To = a.User1
    AND f.Date_Assigned between ('06/12/2014') AND ('06/13/2014')
GROUP BY a.User1, e.Material_Location, f.Material_Location
Order By a.User1, e.Material_Location, f.Material_Location
```

Comment: make your counts DISTINCT

Comment: Wow something so idiotically simple. Thank you.

Comment: of course! after writing a complex query like that its easy to overlook or overthink the solution :) dont forget to accept my answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try putting distinct there... it seems like you are counting double from the left joins

```
SELECT  a.User1
        , isnull(sum(DISTINCT b.Page_Count),0) AS Count1
        , isnull(sum(DISTINCT c.Page_Count),0) AS Count2
        , isnull(sum(DISTINCT d.Page_Count),0) AS Count3
        , e.Material_Location
        , f.Material_Location
From    TaskUser AS a
    LEFT JOIN PaperMaterial AS b
    ON b.Assigned_To = a.User1
    AND b.Date_Assigned between ('06/11/2014') AND ('06/12/2014')
    LEFT JOIN PaperMaterial AS c
    ON c.Assigned_To = a.User1
    AND c.Date_Assigned between ('06/12/2014') AND ('06/13/2014')
    LEFT JOIN PaperMaterial AS d
    ON d.Assigned_To = a.User1
    AND d.Date_Assigned between ('06/09/2014') AND ('06/14/2014')
    LEFT JOIN PaperMaterial AS e
    ON e.Assigned_To = a.User1
    AND e.Date_Assigned between ('06/11/2014') AND ('06/12/2014')
    LEFT JOIN PaperMaterial AS f
    ON f.Assigned_To = a.User1
    AND f.Date_Assigned between ('06/12/2014') AND ('06/13/2014')
GROUP BY a.User1, e.Material_Location, f.Material_Location
Order By a.User1, e.Material_Location, f.Material_Location
```